# Update pandas dataframe and update the value if data exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file like this:

```
word, tag, counter
I, Subject, 1
Love, Verb, 3
Love, Adjective, 1
```

I would like to create a dataframe which column is word and list of tags, like below:

```
Word Subject  Verb  Adjective
I     1        0     0
Love  0        3     1
```

How do I manage to do that with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='word', columns='tag', values='counter').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
tag   Adjective  Subject  Verb
word                          
I             0        1     0
Love          1        0     3
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['word','tag'])['counter'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
tag   Adjective  Subject  Verb
word                          
I             0        1     0
Love          1        0     3
```

but if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

then need aggregate by some `aggfunc` in [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print (df)
   word        tag  counter
0     I    Subject        1
1  Love       Verb        3
2  Love  Adjective        1 <-duplicates for Love and Adjective
3  Love  Adjective        3 <-duplicates for Love and Adjective

df = df.pivot_table(index='word', 
                    columns='tag', 
                    values='counter', 
                    aggfunc='mean', 
                    fill_value=0)
print (df)
tag   Adjective  Subject  Verb
word                          
I             0        1     0
Love          2        0     3
```

Another solution with `groupby` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['word','tag'])['counter'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
tag   Adjective  Subject  Verb
word                          
I             0        1     0
Love          2        0     3
```